# How do device screen resolutions scale in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Following are screen resolutions of a couple popular phones:

iPhone 6: 1334 x 750

Samsung Galaxy S5: 1920x1080

In CSS we have media queries like:

`@media only screen (max-width:600px)`

which is meant for small screens, and the two above phones still respond to this? Clearly their width is much more than `600px`. So my question is, how does this scaling occur, if at all it occurs? I have a feeling I'm missing a fundamental concept of CSS here.

EDIT: I understand that `@media screen` is actually asking for the window size and not the device resolution. My question could be more appropriately phrased as, "how does the window size scale in phone browsers?"

Comment: Just for my reference: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was wondering the same a while ago, so I'll summarize what I found. Turned out to be quite the answer, so I hope it helps.

Pixels themselves have become relative. Having a mobile screen with a high pixel density will not mean that you automatically view a large website on a small screen. Pixel density is used to set determine how many pixels the webpage will use.

> Pixel units are relative to the resolution of the viewing device, i.e., most often a computer display. If the pixel density of the output device is very different from that of a typical computer display, the user agent should rescale pixel values.

So our what does that mean? The CSS pixel has become a grid unit that is decoupled from the actual pixel. And that we should set the pixel density to a value which will make it clear what screen size we're looking on, irrelevant the amount of pixels we actually have. As a web developer, this is why we set the viewport, which sets up the relative grid by dividing the amount of pixels by the pixel density. So a device with 640 pixels width and a 2.0 pixel density will show a 320 pixels wide screen.

**What now?**

There are 2 ways to deal with this. First is to, like I said, set the viewport. But as devices are getting bigger this will lead to a mobile site on screen sizes that might not be intended for the full mobile lay-out.

The other option is to ignore this and start designing responsively. Have two, three or four screen sizes at which you want your lay-out to change and stick to that. Do some research if you have to for certain screen sizes (like: do you want the ipad landscape to be your normal webpage?) and go from there.

Which one is better? I would say setting the viewport, because that allows you to ensure the right content is shown, regardless of the real amount of pixels.

**Further reading**

- A (non-exhaustive) list of device pixel ratio's can be found at http://www.devicepixelratio.com/
- Apple device screen sizes at http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/
- A clear article on it can be found on [gamon.org](http://gamon.org/blog/2013/04/26/css-pixel-ratios-or-why-all-mobile-sites-are-320-pixels/).

Comment: Thank you so much! The visual of pixels becoming a grid unit helps a lot. Just to clarify, what does it mean to "set the viewport". Do you mind providing a code example?

Comment: You're welcome :). You can use the meta tag for that. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)...

and even more, when it comes to scalling and Pixel Game, read [A Pixel Is not Pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

As an excerpt / Point to Ponder

> For pages that set an initial or maximum scale, this means the width
>   property actually translates into a minimum viewport width. For
>   example, if your layout needs at least 500 pixels of width then you
>   can use the following markup. When the screen is more than 500 pixels
>   wide, the browser will expand the viewport (rather than zoom in) to
>   fit the screen

also,

> However, there are two tricky bits: the device-width media query and
>   the  
>   width="device-width"> tag. Both work with device pixels, and not with
>   CSS pixels, because they report on the context of the web page, and
>   not on its inner CSS workings.

Comment: Your answer should include the key information, only supported by the link for further reading - links die.