# How does this CSS media screen target phones that have resolution width 1080p?

Tags: css, screen-resolution

I've seen the CSS media query below recommended to target phones. Yes, it works for my phone. However, my phone, and many others, have resolution width 1080px. How does it work...?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750983/how-do-device-screen-resolutions-scale-in-css this might answer your question

Comment: Thank you @Stackerexp, really interesting and helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every devise has physical pixel size and a ratio for browsers. For instance iPhoneX has with **1125px** and a ratio **3**. So the CSS width will be **375px**.

So for it's screen with physical resolution **1125px** your media will be

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) { }
```

Very good table with devises resolutions, ratios and CSS scale here:

https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices

Although you can determine in `media` the `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` and `orientation`, like this

```
/* iPhone X in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 812px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

More about it here http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: Thank you @focus.style, very interesting and a useful website